# Python3: getting external port from stun server

Tags: udp, python-3.8, stun

I want to get the external port that NAT send udp packet from.
for example:-
when I send a UDP packet:
source ip       ::   source port   ::   destination ip   ::   destination port
192.168.1.20      ::      9000          ::       217.52.8.105      ::                5555
then NAT translates it into:
source ip       ::   source port   ::   destination ip   ::   destination port
121.30.8.158      ::      7777          ::       217.52.8.105      ::                5555

I want to get that 7777 port.
I tried [pystun3](https://pypi.org/project/pystun3/), but it allways says that external port is 54320  (and that is not correct)

I also tried this code, but I can't get port from the recieved stun msg

```
#!/usr/bin/python3
import socket
def long_to_bytes(n, length):  # compatible to PY2 and PY3
    # Equivalent to n.to_bytes(length,byteorder='big') in Python 3
    return bytes(bytearray((n >> i*8) & 0xff for i in range(length-1, -1, -1)))

import secrets
def randint(n): return secrets.randbits(n)
    
sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM)
sock.setsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET, socket.SO_REUSEADDR, 1)
sock.bind(('0.0.0.0', 3425))

BIND_REQUEST_MSG = b'\x00\x01'
BIND_RESPONSE_MSG = b'\x01\x01'
send_data = b''
msg_len = long_to_bytes(len(send_data), 2)
trans_id = long_to_bytes(randint(128), 16)
data = BIND_REQUEST_MSG+msg_len+trans_id+send_data
sock.sendto(data, ('stun.l.google.com', 19302))
recv, addr = sock.recvfrom(2048)
print('recv:', recv)
#output: b'\x01\x01\x00\x0cr\xa7\x14\x05Bu\xfe)\xec?f\xd7\x83\x80\xc6u\x00\x01\x00\x08\x00\x01\ra\xd94\x08i'
# how can I get external port from these bytes ??
```

Comment: Go get `stunclient` from the Stuntman source. It will correctly tell you about your NAT and mapping behavior.  You can use the supplied client program to validate the behavior of your python code.  http://www.stunprotocol.org.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's parse your stun response together. Using the message structure described in [RFC 3478 section 11.1 and on down](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc3489#section-11.1)

This byte string:

```
b'\x01\x01\x00\x0cr\xa7\x14\x05Bu\xfe)\xec?f\xd7\x83\x80\xc6u\x00\x01\x00\x08\x00\x01\ra\xd94\x08i'
```

When printed out in 4 byte rows is this:

```
0x01 0x01 0x00 0x0c
0x72 0xa7 0x14 0x05
0x42 0x75 0xfe 0x29
0xec 0x3f 0x66 0xd7
0x83 0x80 0xc6 0x75
0x00 0x01 0x00 0x08
0x00 0x01 0x0d 0x61
0xd9 0x34 0x08 0x69
```

Row by row:

```
Row 0: 0x01 0x01 0x00 0x0c
```

This is a 4 byte header.  The first two bytes, `0x0101` indicates a binding response.  The subsequent two bytes `0x000c` indicates the total message size after the transaction id is 12 bytes.

The next four rows:

```
Row 1: 0x72 0xa7 0x14 0x05
Row 2: 0x42 0x75 0xfe 0x29
Row 3: 0xec 0x3f 0x66 0xd7
Row 4: 0x83 0x80 0xc6 0x75
```

Is the transaction id. You should validate that it matches the transaction id you sent. But let's assume it it is.

Next comes the individual attribute blocks.

The attribute header is on row 5:

```
row 5: 0x00 0x01 0x00 0x08
```

`0x00 0x01` indicates **MAPPED-ADDRESS**.  `0x00 0x08` indicates the message attribute length is 8 bytes.  And that's the last two rows.

```
row 6: 0x00 0x01 0x0d 0x61
row 7: 0xd9 0x34 0x08 0x69
```

The MAPPED-ADDRESS attribute body for IPv4 always starts the first two bytes with `0x00 0x01`.  Then the subsequent two bytes are your mapped port: `0x0d 0x61` is `3425`  It's not a coincidence this is the same as your local port. Most NATs try to preserve the local port when translating to outbound if it's not used by another socket or device on your network.

And the last row is your IP address as seen by the stun server.  `0xd9 0x34 0x08 0x69` is simply: `217.52.8.105`.

I'm not sure what your local IP address is, but your code uses local port 3425. And the stun servers is indicating that it sees you coming from `217.52.8.105:3425`